# How to free resources when initializing list throws exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

In below code I don’t see A or C’s destructor called. I know I can use smart pointers etc, but in general how should we handle already allocated resources when an initializing list throws?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
  ~C ()
  {
    cout << "destructing C" << endl;
  }
};

class A
{
public:
  A ()
  {
    throw bad_alloc ();
  }
   ~A ()
  {
    cout << "destructing A";
  }
};

class B
{
public:
  B () try:pc (new C ()), pa (new A ())
  {
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    cout << "bad thing happened" << endl;
    throw;
  }


  A *pa;
  C *pc;
};

int
main ()
{
  try
  {
    B b;
  } catch ( ...)
  {
    cout << "i'm catching this bad here" << endl;
  }
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Is it guaranteed to have a leak? If so is the best practice to allocate in constructor body and then do delete in the exception handler there?

Comment: You need to add a destructor in `B`

Comment: @AlanBirtles: In the context of this problem, since the constructor is expected to throw an exception, the destructor (even if it was explicitly defined) would still not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to use smart pointers as you suggest in your question. For example: `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique`.

```
class B {
 public:
  B() : pc(std::make_unique<C>()), pa(std::make_unique<A>()) {}

  std::unique_ptr<C> pc;
  std::unique_ptr<A> pa;
};
```

In this code, if `pa` throws, the destructor for `pc` would still be called.

Comment: So if we use raw pointer, there will have to be a leak no way out here?

Comment: @JingmingZhang You *could* use a raw pointer (there's nothing magic about smart pointers; they do this already), but you'd end up having to reinvent what smart pointers already handle for you, so it's better to just use the smart pointers.

Comment: @JingmingZhang The only way out with raw pointers I can see is rather ugly: we could initialize all the pointers (but at most one) to `nullptr`, and then perform the allocation in the constructor body, where we can check and handle exceptions. If possible, I'd try to use `unique_ptr`s instead.